# Firestore query.get error when retrieving a document: Query.get() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: an array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am receiving the following error when attempting to retrieve a document from a firestore database using a query.  The error is: Uncaught FirebaseError: Function Query.get() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: an array.

As I expected it return an array of documents (as per Google documentation) I am confused by the message?  Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
if (email) {
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection("guarantees").where("customer.email", "==", email)
    .get().then((snap) => {
        let doc = snap.docs[0];
//....
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what the issue, but it looks like `email` is an array and if you want the query to search an array, maybe you can use the following code:

```
if (email) {
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection("guarantees")
       .where("customer.email", "in", email)
       .get()
       .then((snap) => {
          let doc = snap.docs[0];
          console.log(doc.data());
        }); 
   
//....
```

or check the type of `email` isn't an object and use your original code.

check out these [doc's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) they are super helpful.

Comment: Hi @Cleanbeans the email is an address currently in local storage and the Google docs I refer to are the ones you have pointed me too.  That said I am having trouble recreating the issue as I have tried alternative work arounds so best to pause this now unless it reappears.  Thanks for your help.